# Can I specify the auto-commit interval in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a long running INSERT statement in MS SQL Server.  After about an hour, the transaction log runs out of space.  Is it possible to set the auto-commit interval of a session so that it flushes the transaction log after so many records have been inserted?

Comment: Committing the transaction will NOT free up transaction log space, unless the database is using the simple recovery model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by **jl** is good. I would also consider looking at your insert strategy. Could you perhaps leverage the efficiencies gained by [Bulk Inserts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)? If Bulk Inserts aren't your answer, then cutting up your job into batches of inserts as **jl** suggested is probably the way to go.

One other thing to consider is dropping your indexes prior to inserts and recreating them after your insert. For a job this intensive, that could significantly cut down the time to execute it. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751039/slow-bulk-insert-for-table-with-many-indexes))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have already considered (and may already be using) an explicit transaction  that commits after X INSERTS have been performed.

These might be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602244/batch-commit-on-large-insert-operation-in-native-sql

http://sqlserverplanet.com/data-warehouse/transferring-large-amounts-of-data-using-batch-inserts/